# Why the basis is the matrix's eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Consider a linear transformation given by the matrix
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Find a basis for $R^4$ with respect to which the matrix representation for the linear transformation above is diagonal.

Why the basis is the linear independent eigenvectors of matrix $A$? How does it come?

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that,  for an eigenvector $v$, we have $Av=\lambda v$ for the corresponding eigenvalue value $\lambda$.

Let $B$ be the matrix of eigenvectors.   Then $B^{-1}AB=D$ is equivalent to $AB=BD$.   Now use $Av=\lambda v$ to see that $D$ will consist precisely of the eigenvalues on the diagonal. Both sides have $i$th column equal to $\lambda_iv_i$, where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue and $v_i$ the $i$th eigenvector.

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. AB will not be equal to DB it will be equal to BD

Comment: @HarshitGupta you're right.  I blew that.

Answer (score 0):

A $4\times 4$ matrix has at most $4$ eigenvalues. A whole subspace of eigenvectors must correspond to each eigenvalue (of course, there are a lot of things that I did not cover as is the multiplicity of each, the dimension of each eigenspace and all of that).

Ideally, you could choose four eigenvectors from all of them that form a basis for the whole space. And how does this help us?

If $\beta = \{ v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \}$ is the desired basis, each vector $v_i$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, then note the following
$$Av_1=\lambda_1 v_1=\lambda_1 v_1+0v_2+0v_3+0v_4$$
$$Av_2=\lambda_2 v_2=0v_1+\lambda_2 v_2+0v_3+0v_4$$
$$Av_3=\lambda_3 v_3=0v_1+0v_2+\lambda_3 v_3+0v_4$$
$$Av_4=\lambda_4 v_4=0v_1+0v_2+0v_3+\lambda_4 v_4$$
How is the matrix representation of $A$ with respect to that basis $\beta$? You see?